# Usage of collection sort in android

Tags: java, android, sorting

I'm having array of list like this

```
array list={Rank,Shyam,"Sores","Hintus",Ander}
```

I'm using `Collections.sort(arraylist);`

I'm getting like this:

```
"Hintus"
"Sores"
Ander
Rank
```

I'm getting strings with special characters before any other string in my list.

But I want to get results like this:

```
Ander
Rank
"Hintus"
"Sores"
```

How do I get desired order?

Answer (score 4):

Specify a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that ignores them... note that this *may* be costly.

```
Collectons.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {

  public int compare(final String a, final String b) {
    return a.replace("\"", "").compareTo(b.replace("\"", ""));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a comparator by your own, and in comparator, write your sorting criteria. and then sort the arraylist using this comparator.